# Is it possible to put buttons on menu bar (file edit view help) after help in VS2022?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I have developed a C++ console application(a proof checker) working with text files in VS2022 and now trying to make it a truly Windows application. So I need to create for each text file button with the name of the text file. And clicking such a button should initiate the execution of the proof checker
for this text file. So my question is:

Can I put the buttons on the Menu bar(file edit view help) just after help?

I googled the question but with no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to create a new C++ project in VS2022. 
I found the following reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170

Should I use this reference or maybe there are better choices?
In the book "Visual C++ 5" by S.Holzner I saw a (maybe) simpler way using MFC AppWizard.